# CiviCRM reports do not support unicode

Tags: issues, reports

Some reports do not support unicode characters in contact names:

**Contact reports:**

- Activity summary
- Contact Logging Report (Summary)

[image]

Comment: Confirmed on http://dmaster.demo.civicrm.org/civicrm/report/instance/44

Comment: This is not a question, it is a fact. It probably helps to ask a question of you want answers.